# How Ruby allocate memory on boot?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, database, heroku, memory

I'm using rails on Heorku. After restarting my app on heroku, I've got about 400-500 MB memory peak (about 20M objects is allocated). Also it takes some time before it is ready to use. If I'm for example on home page and don't use any other controller than application controller it's fine. But when I go to some page, where another controller is used, the peak happens and it's always the same size, doesn't matter which page I'm requesting.

I've tried to measure it somehow, but without any success.
I'm using Scout, where I can see this memory bloat, but it doesn't help me a lot, because it shows a peak depends which page I requested first.

It looks like Ruby allocates some memory "in case", based on my app structure, models, controllers... (?) . Doesn anybody have something similar? Is it something that is expected?

I have thousands of records in DB, but even if I clear my DB, ruby reserve this memory in the same way.
Ruby ver. 2.4.2, Rails 5.1.4
I'm using some fragment caching and when app is loaded (with memory 400-500MB) it's working normally, isn't slow.

Comment: If the issue is memory on boot then you can try jruby and then allocate as much or as little memory to JVM as you need

Comment: Thanks Ruslan, I think I found the reason for this issue. It's connected with asset_path and image_tag . I will dig this more and share the results here. I will test jruby anyway, when I will fix this issue.

Comment: mildly related here are some ruby gc tuning params https://collectiveidea.com/blog/archives/2015/02/19/optimizing-rails-for-memory-usage-part-2-tuning-the-gc